# how to visualize transition in a loop

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, transition, force-layout

I am stuck by a tricky problem now. In d3js framework, I set up a force directed layout. The node object is in such a structure as shown below,

```
{
    ID: someID
    animationCount: someInt   
    animationSet:{                    
        animation1:{
            time: time1
            color: color1
        }
        animation2:{
            time: time2
            color: color2
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Each node has a set of animations to be visualized, and the animation count may be different for different nodes. Now I want to conduct transitions for all the nodes, the number of transitions is dependent on the animation counts, start time of each transition, i.e. 'delay', is dependent on the 'time', and the main animation is the change of filled color.

Anyone has some suggestions for this case, i.e. conduct transitions for multiple elements, and each should be conducted in a loop, the number of iterations of which is according to the animation count.

Answer (score 0):

after a couple of hours of struggling, I think I get a solution myself. The code is provided as a reference, for you may be also stuck into such a problem.

```
    d3.selectAll('circle').each(function(d){
        var trans=d.animationSet;
        var c=d.animationCount;
        var sel=d3.select(this);
        for(i=0;i<c;i++){
            var transItem=trans['animation'+i]
            var sel=sel.transition()
                .delay(time_scale(Date.parse(transItem.time)))
                .duration(2000)
                .style("fill",fill(transItem.color))
                .each("end",function(){d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .delay(5000)
                .style("fill",d3.rgb("#fff")
                .brighter())
                .duration(5000)});
        }                   
    })
```